# How to install older version (revert) of Yeoman generator?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Is there a way to revert back to an older version of some yeoman generator? Specifically I'm using this https://github.com/keshavos/generator-angularjs-cordova for my project and the latest update has something wrong with $http so I'd like to go back to older version (0.2.2 in this case) until it's fixed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It turns out something changed in versions and I had to escape special characters in URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
npm install -g generator-angularjs-cordova@0.2.2
```